# Subseting data from data frame columns that match key words

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame with 30 columns, one of the column variables is peoples titles. These don't follow any group or structure as many of the titles are unique, however I want to select all the titles that have certain words in them, such as "leader" or "integrated".

I've tried using the following select dplyr function:

```
df1<-select(df, Title, contains('digital'))
```

However this didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just try `df[grep("\\b(leader|integrated)\\b", df$Title),]`  It is not clear whether you are subsetting row or columns.  The `select` method is for subsetting columns, but from the description it seems like you want to subset the rows based on some strings in the 'Title' column.  It wouldn't hurt to give a small reproducible example along with the expected output.

Comment: First subset your required columns (select is for columns). Then find in the subset, exemple here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782218/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-value-in-r-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `filter` and `grepl` like in this example:

```
iris %>% filter( grepl( "set" , Species))
```

Here, `Species` is the column I am matching "set" to.