# Select rows in R

Tags: r, tidyr

*editing to provide further clarification on the requirement*
I'm fairly new in R and I've currently encountered a road block when I was tidying up my data.

My current data looks like this.

```
    Data
1   AAA TEXT Here
2   ZX
3   YX
4   ****
5   BBB Text Here
6   AL
7   TP
8   XY
9   ******
10 CCC Text Here
11 PP
12 QV
13 ******
```

AAA, BBB, CCC are like my 'identifiers' and the *** means the end of the related lines to the identifiers. In this sample output, I would only want to extract BBB and the next 3 lines after it. I would need to select in-between rows and transform my table to just this:

```
    Data
1   BBB Text Here
2   AL
3   TP
4   XY
```

Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: Format the question properly, add information on your efforts to the problem. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Edited. Thank you!

Comment: In case if no one answers your question, you can try editing it with more information about your efforts to solving the problem.

Comment: What happens to the other lines of text? Why only output the lines between `BBB Text Here` and `Text Again`?

Comment: Why did you exclude rows 10:13, even though its between 2 separating lines?

Comment: Basically, the AAA, BBB, and CCC are my identifiers. And I only need to get the lines related to the identifiers. So here, I only need to output BBB and the next three lines.

Comment: How is your data stored?  Is it one big text string, or is it a list of lines?

Comment: The original data is one big text string. Then, I split it per new line and assign every line into a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Your method of data storage is not what any of us would recommend, but if what you have written is indeed how you have stored your data then you can use a method outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782218/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-value-in-r-code) to find the row number of the line matching your specified identifier.

```
# Set up test 'identifier' value
WantedIdentifier = "BBB Text Here"

# Get matching  row number 
RowNo = 
  which(Text == WantedIdentifier, arr.ind=TRUE)[1]

# Return from that row to the third beyond 
ReturnedText = 
  if(!is.na(RowNo)) data.frame(Data = Text[RowNo:(RowNo+3),]) else NA

# Value returned
> ReturnedText
           Data
1 BBB Text Here
2            AL
3            TP
4            XY
```

Test data setup

```
Text= 
  read.table(text = "Data 
  'AAA TEXT Here'
  'ZX'
  'YX'
  '****'
  'BBB Text Here'
  'AL'
  'TP'
  'XY'
  '******'
  'CCC Text Here'
  'PP'
  'QV'
  '******'", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks, Stewart! Your suggestion worked! Actually, the original data is just one cell and I've split it by new line and assign it as a new row thus the data above. Thank you so much for your help!