# R read excel until you reach a certain criteria

Tags: r, excel, string, readxl

I have a messy excel file that I need to read in as is, but I want to read the file in until it hits the row that says "Projects as usual"

This value will always be in the first column, and no other string in that column will ever match it. I also don't want any of the information below it in other columns because it's making my numeric columns be read in as strings (see example below with score).

For example, we can pretend this is the excel file:

```
library(tidyverse)

messy_excel <- tibble(id = c("1", "2", NA, NA, "Projects as usual", NA),
name = c("Joe", "Justin", NA, NA, NA, "Other info I don't want"),
score = c("50", "20", NA, NA, NA, "This shouldn't show"))
```

And this is what I want:

```
library(tidyverse)
beautiful_excel <- tibble(id = c("1", "2"),
name = c("Joe", "Justin"),
score = c(50, 20))
~~~~~

Thank you!
```

Comment: I think you'll need to read the whole file in. Is there something wroing with finding the matching row, then subsetting out the columns below that? It's trivial to convert the columns back to numeric using `as.numeric`.

Comment: Or read it in once,  use the strings to decide the row limit,  then read again only up to te desired row.

Comment: @AllanCameron, how would you remove all information below a set criteria? I want to delete all rows that start at that level

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Based on @G5W's suggestion, I filtered for where the value was, getting inspiration from this answer: [How to find row number of a value in R code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782218/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-value-in-r-code)

Specifically, I assigned each row a row number, detected where the target string was, and removed that row and the ones below it. I then used the retype() function from the hablar package to fix the column types.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hablar)

messy_excel <- tibble(id = c("1", "2", NA, NA, "Projects as usual", NA),
name = c("Joe", "Justin", NA, NA, NA, "Other info I don't want"),
score = c("50", "20", NA, NA, NA, "This shouldn't show"))

#Give each line a row number
messy_excel$row_num <- seq.int(nrow(messy_excel))

#Identify the row where the garbage starts
messy_row <- which(grepl("Projects as usual", messy_excel$id))

#remove all rows below the garbage, remove the row_num column, correct column types, and remove the rows of all nas
clean_excel <- messy_excel %>%
  filter(row_num < messy_row) %>%
  dplyr::select(-row_num) %>%
  retype() %>%
  na.omit()

glimpse(clean_excel)
```