# How to address the problem about json text?

Tags: r, json

I wrote a function to get access API data but there is problem with json text.
codes are shown below

```
 get_stats <- function (base_url2, link2,...){
     base_url2 <- "https://gitlab.com/dword4/nhlapi/-/blob/master/stats-api.md"
    full_url2 <- paste0 (base_url2,"/?expand=team.stats")
    get_url <- GET (full_url2)
    stats_txt <- content (get_url, "text", encoding = "UTF-8")
    stats_json <- fromJSON (stats_txt, flatten=TRUE)
    stats_df <- data.frame(stats_json)
    return(stats_df)
  }
   stats_Data <- get_stats(base_url2)
```

Error message:
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
 <html class=""
(right here) ------^

Does anybody have an idea to address this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find row number of a value in R code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20782218/how-to-find-row-number-of-a-value-in-r-code)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
dat <- data.frame(teamID = c('ARI','ATL','BAL','MIN'))
dat
  teamID
1    ARI
2    ATL
3    BAL
4    MIN
rownames(dat)[dat$teamID == 'MIN']
[1] "4"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `which()` function returns the index of values that are `TRUE`.

```r
dat <- data.frame(teamID = c('ARI','ATL','BAL','MIN'))

which(dat$teamID == 'MIN')
#> [1] 4
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>